# how to send request in rails console with session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, controller

I know I can use `app.get` and `app.post` to test controller in Rails console.

But how to set the `session`? I found there is `app.session`, but it seems not to preserve its status.

```
   $ app.session[:a] = "123"
   $ app.get "/"
   $ app.session
   => {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RedisStore for your Rails sessions, you can retrieve a session with the following handy method given a session id

```
def get_session(sid)
  store = ActionDispatch::Session::RedisStore.new(
      Rails.application,
      Rails.application.config.session_options)
  store.get_session({}, sid)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [blog post](http://teamco-anthill.blogspot.com/2011/05/ruby-on-rails-how-to-load-session.html) about it. Judging by how tedious it is my guess is that people usually don't do this.

> Look in tmp/sessions and find the most recent file (ls -alrt on UNIX).
>   Let's say the file is called `tmp/sessions/ruby_sess.8eb9614a7e4e1e3b`
>   Open console and type:
>
> ```
> >> session = Marshal.load(File.open('tmp/sessions/ruby_sess.8eb9614a7e4e1e3b'))
> => {"hash"=>{:cart=...
> >> cart = session["hash"][:cart]
> ....
> ```
>
> In this case I was trying to access a cart object in the session, which was placed in the session with `session[:cart] =
>   Cart.new`